# Show that $T^S$ with an evaluation is indeed the exponential in the functor category $\hat{\mathbf{C}}=\mathbf{Sets}^{\mathbf{C}^{{\rm op}}}.$

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, functors

*I'd like to apologise in advance for the mixture of different notations.*

This is **Exercise I.8** of Mac Lane and Moerdijk's, *"Sheaves in Geometry and Logic [. . .]"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Chat%7B%5Cmathbf%7BC%7D%7D%24%2C%20exponential%2C%20functor%20category%2C%20sheaves%20in%20geometry%20and%20logic&p=1), this is new to MSE.

### The Details:

From p. 17 *ibid.* . . .

> **Definition 1:** Given two functors
>
> $$F:\mathbf{X}\to \mathbf{A}\quad G: \mathbf{A}\to \mathbf{X},$$
>
> we say that $G$ is *right adjoint* to $F$, written $F\dashv G$, when for any $X\in{\rm Ob}(\mathbf{X})$ and any $A\in{\rm Ob}(\mathbf{A})$, there is a natural bijection between morphisms
>
> $$\frac{X\stackrel{f}{\to}G(A)}{F(X)\stackrel{h}{\to}A},$$
>
> in the sense that each $f$, as displayed, uniquely determines $h$, and conversely.

From p. 19 *ibid.* . . .

> **Definition 2:** Suppose products exist in $\mathbf{C}$. For a fixed $A\in{\rm Ob}(\mathbf{C})$, one may consider the functor
>
> $$A\times -: \mathbf{C}\to \mathbf{C}.$$
>
> If this functor had a right adjoint (unique up to isomorphism), this adjoint is denoted  by
>
> $$(-)^A:\mathbf{C}\to \mathbf{C}.$$
>
> In this case $A$ is said to be an *exponentiable* object of $\mathbf{C}$.

### The Question:

> Consider a small category $\mathbf{C}$. For each object $B$ of $\mathbf{C}$ there is a functor $D_B: \mathbf{C} / B \to \mathbf{C}$ defined by taking the domain of each arrow to $B$. Hence, each $T: \mathbf{C}^{{\rm op}} \to\mathbf{Sets}$ yields $T_B = T \circ
> D^{{\rm op}}: (\mathbf{C} / B)^{{\rm op}} \to\mathbf{Sets}$. Define an exponential $T^S$ by
>
> $$T^S(B)={\rm Hom}_{\widehat{(\mathbf{C}/B)}}(S_B, T_B),$$
>
> with the evident evaluations${}^\dagger$ $e_B: T^S(B) \times S(B) \to T(B)$. Show that $T^S$ with this evaluation $e$ is indeed the exponential in the functor category $\hat{\mathbf{C}}=\mathbf{Sets}^{\mathbf{C}^{{\rm op}}}.$

### Thoughts:

My experience with functor categories and exponents therein is best portrayed by  [**$\S 9.3$(Exponentiation in $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathscr{C}}$)**](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=AprOBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA208&lpg=PA208&dq=goldblatt+%22the+collection+of+natural+transformations+from%22&source=bl&ots=AV2o_x53sS&sig=ACfU3U3Jj5ttNXRO18Setim6zyCTbzndKg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0jJme8NHnAhU8QhUIHa-EAx0Q6AEwAHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=goldblatt%20%22the%20collection%20of%20natural%20transformations%20from%22&f=false) of Goldblatt's, *"Topoi: [. . .]"*.

In Goldblatt's book, for $F:\mathscr{C}\to\mathbf{Set}$ (in his notation) and a $\mathscr{C}$-object $a$, it delineates the "forgetful functor" $F_a:\mathscr{C}\uparrow a \to \mathbf{Set}$ by $$(a\stackrel{f}{\to}b)\mapsto F(b)$$ and, for $g: a\to c$, $F_a$ sends an $h: f\to g$, where $h\circ f=g$, to $F(h)$. It then defines, for $F, G:\mathscr{C}\to \mathbf{Set}$, the exponent $G^F$ by

$$G^F(a)={\rm Nat}[F_a, G_a],$$ the collection of natural transformations from $F_a$ to $G_a$.

Now, this is not quite the same as in *"Sheaves [. . .]"*; neither is the evaluation arrow described in *"Topoi: [. . .]* (which I'll leave to you to look up in the link above). But they give me a rough idea of how to flesh out the exponential in question.

Nevertheless, I feel I am on unsure footing.

> How do I translate from Goldblatt's book to Mac Lane & Moerdijk's to do **Exercise I.8**?

Please help  :)

---

$\dagger$ I'm not sure what those evaluations are supposed to be.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Hi Shaun ! (I’m not the one downvoting) It doesn’t seem clear that you have identified what you need to show in order to get that $T^S$ is the exponential, what is the definition you are trying to check $T^S$ satisfies ? Once you have done this, do you have an explicit description of  the “evident” evaluations ?

Comment: Hi @jeanmfischer. I've made an edit. Is that better?

Comment: Hint on $e_B$: we have $S(B) = S_B(\langle B, \operatorname{id}_B \rangle)$ where $\langle B, \operatorname{id}_B \rangle$ is the final object of $\mathbf{C} / B$.

Comment: That said, I'm not sure what differences you're seeing.  MacLane and Moerdik's $T_B$ amounts to the same thing as Goldblatt's $F_a$, and MacLane and Moerdik's $T^S$ amounts to the same thing as Goldblatt's $G^F$.

Comment: Although I guess MacLane and Moerdik's wording is a bit confusing: it took me a while to realize it should be parsed as "take the domain of (each arrow to $B$)" as opposed to "take (the domain of each arrow) to $B$".

Comment: Nor am I, @DanielSchepler; I suppose it's a lack of confidence. I'm teaching myself topos theory. The slight ambiguity in Mac Lane and Moerdijk here, as you pointed out, doesn't help either. Thank you for the hint!

Comment: Actually, the formulation I'm most familiar with is: $[\mathscr{F}, \mathscr{G}](U) = \operatorname{Hom}(\mathscr{F} \times \hat U, \mathscr{G})$ where $\hat U$ is the presheaf $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{C}}({-}, U)$.  (Where $\hat U$ is notable as representing the functor of "sections over $U$", $\mathbf{Set}^{C^{op}} \to \mathbf{Set}, \mathscr{F} \mapsto \mathscr{F}(U))$.)  It takes a bit more work, but not much, to establish the equivalence to MacLane and Moerdik's definition.  And with that formulation, maybe it's easier to see that $[\mathscr{F}, \mathscr{G}]$ is indeed the exponential.